# angularjs ng-repeat nested array into one unique list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to get the list of all values from a nested array for all objects into one list. 
I have the following json file structure:

```
{
    "booklist": {
        "fiction": [
          {
            "key": "book1",
            "value": "bookvalue1"
          },
          {
            "key": "book2",
            "value": "bookvalue2"
          }
        ],
        "romance": [
          {
            "key": "book3",
            "value": "bookvalue3"
          },
          {
            "key": "book4",
            "value": "bookvalue4"
          }
        ],
        "thriller": [
          {
            "key": "book5",
            "value": "bookvalue5"
          },
          {
            "key": "book6",
            "value": "bookvalue6"
          }
        ]         
}
```

I am trying (what i have tried) to read the list of all books in my dropdown menu:

```
<ui-select name="books" ng-model="model.books" theme="selectize" required>
    <ui-select-match> {{$select.selected.value}} </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices
            repeat="r.key as r in booklist | filter: $select.search">
        <div ng-bind-html="r.value | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

so that the dropdown menu will look like this:

```
bookvalue1
bookvalue2
bookvalue3
bookvalue4
bookvalue5
bookvalue6
```

and in another input element, i want to get the category of the selected book above:

```
<input type="text" name="category" ng-model="model.category" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" value="??"/>
```

how to get the value for the category of the selected book above?

**The ultimate goal is to pass the category value and the book value into my model separately.**

### important note:

i am not allowed to change the json structure, it should remain as it is. I just have to change and adapt the code to read the info the right way.

Comment: Map a flattened array in your controller

Comment: Or create new filter for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [this code](http://embed.plnkr.co/V2IPyISGrEAkFxXqkHeq/),
but i suggest for [grouping books](http://embed.plnkr.co/mUrsQA0da6uvADpeqAKK/)

Comment: why is the category model empty after selecting? thanks

Comment: Hi @passion, do you mean `ctrl.selectedValue` is empty after selecting?

Comment: i would like to have the following as a result of the selection in the first dropdown menu, the second input field is unnecessary: `{{ctrl.model.category}}` which will be **fiction** for example, and `{{ctrl.model.value}}` will be **bookvalue1**

Comment: as you can see in my original post, my ultimate goal is to pass the value and category to another ng-model as the value for this new ng-model. for example, `ng-model="model.category"` will get its default value from the above dropdown selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some custom filter like below:

```
array1 = {
"booklist": {
    "fiction": [
      {
        "key": "book1",
        "value": "bookvalue1"
      },
      {
        "key": "book2",
        "value": "bookvalue2"
      }
    ],
    "romance": [
      {
        "key": "book3",
        "value": "bookvalue3"
      },
      {
        "key": "book4",
        "value": "bookvalue4"
      }
    ],
    "thriller": [
      {
        "key": "book5",
        "value": "bookvalue5"
      },
      {
        "key": "book6",
        "value": "bookvalue6"
      }
    ]
```

}

```
.filter('filter', function(){
    return function(array1, searchTxt){
    angular.forEach(array1, function(v,k){
        if(v.value.indexOf(searchTxt) > -1){
          angular.forEach(v, function(v1, k1){
              return v1;
          })
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Note: I have not tested, kindly do the needed changes.

Comment: can you explain more what to do? by the way, i am not allowed to change the array strucutre in the json file, it should remain the same.

Comment: Sorry json format i have updated is wrong. now its corrected.

Comment: Is your output `bookvalue1
bookvalue2
bookvalue3
bookvalue4
bookvalue5
bookvalue6` should from either filter or highlight?

Comment: so what should the ng-repeat should look like then? can you give a full example answer, please?

Answer (score -2):

Combine array if you want to display in single dropdown. like this

```
 {
        "booklist": {
              {
                "key": "book1",
                "value": "bookvalue1"
              },
              {
                "key": "book2",
                "value": "bookvalue2"
              },
              {
                "key": "book3",
                "value": "bookvalue3"
              },
              {
                "key": "book4",
                "value": "bookvalue4"
              },
              {
                "key": "book5",
                "value": "bookvalue5"
              },
              {
                "key": "book6",
                "value": "bookvalue6"
              }

}
```

or use

```
<ui-select-choices
            repeat="r.key as r in booklist.fiction | filter: $select.search">
        <div ng-bind-html="r.value | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
```

Comment: i want the list of all books, not just the fiction ones.

Comment: That's why i first suggested to combine three array because you can't use multiple ui-select-choices in one ui-select.

Comment: yes, that is why i am not also allowed to merge them all into one array. it should be as it is.

Comment: What you are asking is impossible. as i mentioned above you can't bind multiple array in single select.